# How to share Global count variable between two modules in Angular?

Tags: angular, redux, module

In My application I have different lazy loaded module and in each module I need a Count which would be only one for all module 
e.g if i increment count in shopping module so i should get this incremented count in payment module
how can I achieve ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the count in two components in following way :

1. Create a `shared.service.ts` in which  you declare getter setter in following way  and add into `App.module.ts`;

```js
// shared.service.ts


import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()

export class SharedService {
 
 public count =0;

setCount(countValue:number){
  this.count+= countValue; 
}
getCount():number{
  return this.count;
}

}
```

> Services declared in app.module have scope in entire app  and they are
>   initialised only once

So your doubt that : "this would initialise count again to 0 in another module i want to update this count in one module and want to access that modified count in another module" will not happen.

Now in each component where you want to use counter , just call setter and getter functions using the shared service .

Here is the working example :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ft4etg

PS : Although the example doesn't have lazy loading implemented but to understand the behaviour its sufficient.

Comment: @programaholic is there any way to subscribe the count so i can get it asynchronously. Will redux help for the same?

Comment: How do you want to get it asynchronously ? Can you explain

Answer (score 1):

The best method is to use a shared service. Your service can be accessed by components in each module, and is set up simply:

```
export class CounterService {
  public counter = 0;

  constructor() { }

  incrementCounter(): void {
    this.counter++;
  }

  getCounter(): void {
    return this.counter;
  }
}
```

This has two obvious methods to call, incrementCounter() to add 1 each time, and a get method. You could have (for example) a setCounter() where you can set the value, or a decrementCounter() to reduce by one.

Comment: thank you! but this would initialise count again to 0 in another module i want to update this count in one module and want to access that modified count in another module